# Handling AcquireConnection error

Tags: ssis

I wanted to figure out if a SSIS package would run without any problems by implementing a Health Check script task at the beginning of my package. I did this by iterating through the connection managers in the package and calling the acquireconnection method. If there is an exception acquiring connection, I handle it using catch block and assume that this error would not cause the package to fail. The package shows a successful run but an error gets logged in the “Execution Results/Progress” tab of the SSIS and leads to the failure of the corresponding ExecutePackage Task of the Parent package.

If I throw an exception explicitly within the try block, the parent package doesn’t fail. This failure seems to be happening only when an exception gets thrown by the execution of the acquire connection method.

I am looking understand why this happens and if there is a way I can prevent the parent package from failing whenever acquire connection call throws an exception. I am also open to an alternate approach to figure out if all connection managers within a package will work alright.

Comment: Im not sure if I follow.. Do you want the parent package to fail or not?

Comment: I dont want the parent package to fail.I also dont want the error thrown by AcquireConnection to be logged in the Execution Results of the current package which is happening even after error being handled in the catch block.